# Scala Spring JdbcTemplate - implicit conversion

Tags: spring, scala, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm just learning Scala and trying to create different scenarios with Spring.

The following code executes perfectly:

```
def insert(student: Student): Unit = {

  jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)",
        new PreparedStatementSetter() {
          def setValues(ps: PreparedStatement) {
            ps.setString(1, student.id)
            ps.setString(2, student.firstName)
            ps.setString(3, student.lastName)
          }
        })
    }
  }
```

However, when I try to create PreparedStatementSetter implicitly, my SQL code fails.

my implicit function is:

```
implicit def preparedStatementSetterImplicit(student: Student) = {
  new PreparedStatementSetter() {
    def setValues(ps: PreparedStatement) {
      ps.setString(1, student.id)
      ps.setString(2, student.firstName)
      ps.setString(3, student.lastName)
    }
  } 
}
```

and I'm trying to use it the following way:

```
def insert(student: Student): Unit = {

  jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)",
                            student)
}
```

and my SQL insert fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
```

What's wrong in my implicit conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't need to do an implicit conversion because  `jdbcTemplate.update` has an overloaded type signature which only requires `String` and `Object...` which will match with `String` and `Student` without needing an implicit conversion. You can do this explicitly (which I think looks better for readability in code) like this:

```
  implicit class preparedStatementSetterImplicit(student: Student) {
    def toPreparedStatement() = {
      new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        def setValues(ps: PreparedStatement) {
          ps.setString(1, student.id)
          ps.setString(2, student.firstName)
          ps.setString(3, student.lastName)
        }
      }
    }
  }

 def insert(student: Student) {
            jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)",
                            student.toPreparedStatement())
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly typing your conversion, like:

```
implicit def student2pss(student: Student) : PreparedStatementSetter = {...}
```

Implicit conversions are used only when the type after conversion matches exactly expected type (and without explicit typing your conversion returns something of anonymous type, not exactly `PreparedStatementSetter`), so I'm not sure whether the conversion is being used at all. Try adding `println` to the conversion to see if it's getting fired.

**EDIT:**
To solve the issue, you might want to create your own wrapper for `JdbcTemplate` and provide a conversion to it:

```
class JdbcTemplateWrapper(val template: JdbcTemplate) {
    def wrappedUpdate[DataType](statement: String, data: DataType)(implicit conv: DataType => PreparedStatementSetter) = {
        template.update(statement, conv(data))
    }
}
object JdbcTemplateWrapper {
    implicit def wrapJdbc(template: JdbcTemplate) = new JdbcTemplateWrapper(template)
}
```

Having that in scope, a line

```
jdbcTemplate.customUpdate("INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)",
                        student)
```

would first implicitly convert `jdbcTemplate` to `JdbcTemplateWrapper` (in order to make it respond to `cusomUpdate` and then implicitly convert `Student` to `PreparedStatementSetter`.

Comment: Unfortunately, conversion does not take place - nothing printed after I added println, adding PreparedStatementSetter in return gives the same effect.

Comment: In order to force conversion, you can use a wrapper, as I suggested in  my edit. Does this solve the problem for you?